# How use javascript in web site designed by c#

Tags: asp.net

**How can I write below java code in my web site which designed by c#

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

txt = "<p>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</p>"; 
txt+= "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>"; 
txt+= "<p>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</p>"; 
txt+= "<p>Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</p>"; 
txt+= "<p>Platform: " + navigator.platform + "</p>"; 
txt+= "<p>User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "</p>"; 

document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=txt;**
```

Answer (score 1):

A guess (if it is wrong, please extend your question to state what really is the problem):

The "txt" variable is a C# variable in the codebehind and you want to use the value in javascript.

1) Change your HTML/javascript code to

```
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=<%= GetTxt() %>;
```

2) Add a `GetTxt()` method to your codebehind that delivers the contents of your txt variable, **including surrounding quotes** and **making sure that the resulting javascript is valid** (escaped inner quotes etc).

This method is used when rendering the page server-side. The result of that method is sent as part of your javascript line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the same fashion as if the website wasn't made in C#. Place your javascript code in a script-tag in the source code of your page ( **not code behind** ).

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // put your script here
    </script>
</head>
...
</html>
```

**edit:**

To get the client ID of a control - in case it is a C# WebControl, not a HTML form element - you can use `txt.ClientID`.

In your javascript, that would create:

`myJsTextBox = document.getElementById("<%= txt.ClientID%>");`